# Puppeteer cluster example throwing Error: Unable to get browser page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm using this example in the [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/master/examples/minimal.js) docs

I am running this on node v10.15.3 I have attempted passing the headless property and slowMo to puppeteer options.

I would expect the code to log out and create a Screenshot of the page however, what happens is several chrome instances boot up which do not load any of the pages then the console hangs and errors with:

```
(node:30826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to get browser page
    at Worker.<anonymous> (/Users/Starlord/Code/oppose/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Worker.js:43:31)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/Starlord/Code/oppose/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Worker.js:4:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:30826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 21)
(node:30826) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:30826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to get browser page
    at Worker.<anonymous> (/Users/Starlord/Code/oppose/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Worker.js:43:31)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/Starlord/Code/oppose/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Worker.js:4:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:30826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 22)
^Cinternal/process/per_thread.js:198
      throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
      ^

Error: kill ESRCH
    at process.kill (internal/process/per_thread.js:198:13)
    at process.killChrome (/Users/Starlord/Code/oppose/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:110:17)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

Comment: Author of the library here. This happens when the opening of a new page fails several times. Most of the time, there are some other issues like memory/disk/CPU restrictions that might make the browser crash. Can you add the [debugging logs](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#debugging)? Then I can exactly tell you why the error happens.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly! https://pastebin.com/9d3JB3aA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error happens when the library is unable to create a new browser page. The error is thrown [here](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/b9a883e73c15ad0edc5d25020940d338935e0869/src/Worker.ts#L75) after several tries of opening a new context/page/browser (depending on your settings).

**Debugging log**

To get more information on what causes the error, you can check the [debugging log](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#debugging). This starts the application in debugging mode and will log more information. To enter debugging mode you need to start the application with the environment variable `DEBUG='puppeteer-cluster:*'`:

```sh
# Linux
DEBUG='puppeteer-cluster:*' node application.js
# Windows Powershell
$env:DEBUG='puppeteer-cluster:*';node application.js
```

**Problem**

In your case the debug logs shows (copied from your comment above):

> puppeteer-cluster: Worker Error getting browser page (try: 9), message: this.browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext is not a function +660ms

This means, there is no `createIncognitoBrowserContext` that the library can use to create a new context. As you already confirmed, this is the case, because you are using an old puppeteer installation. To use the setting `{ concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT }`, you have to be using at least [version 1.5.0](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/releases/tag/v1.5.0) as that was when contexts were introduced.

**Fix**

To fix the problem, update your puppeteer installation:

```
npm install puppeteer@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using puppeteer-pool before puppeteer-cluster which uses an older version of puppeteer.

I removed puppeteer-pool and installed puppeteer and it works as expected